# What 2 values are being compared in this Assembly cmp instruction?

Tags: assembly

I have a puzzle where i must reverse-engineer a function to decipher what the correct function inputs are (in order to proceed to the next function). While debugging, I used the following as my function input:

```
6 d 358
```

Now I'm stepping through `gdb` debugger to see if the input was correct.

---

When running `gdb` in AT&T syntax, I've run in to the following `cmp` instruction:

```
0x0040107b <+315>:   movzbl -0x19(%ebp),%eax
0x0040107f <+319>:   cmp    %al,-0x9(%ebp)
0x00401082 <+322>:   je     0x401089 <phase_3+329>
```

This `cmp` instruction is theoretically comparing one of my inputs (either `6`, `d`, or `358`) to `%al`.

I ran:

```
(gdb) i r al
al             0x64     100
```

...to find that the value at `%al` was **100**.

So whatever value is at `-0x9(%ebp)` is being compared to **100**. But how do I determine what value is stored at `-0x9(%ebp)`?

I tried seeing what decimal value/string value was stored at `%ebp` with the following commands:

```
(gdb) i r ebp
ebp            0xbfffef58    0xbfffef58
(gdb) x/d 0xbfffef58
0xbfffef58:    -104
(gdb) x/s 0xbfffef58
0xbfffef58:    "\230\357\377\277\003\016@"
```

...but neither `-104` nor `\230\357\377\277\003\016@` are inputs I entered into the function.

I assume the `-0x9` prefix is referring to another address to get the value. I'm thinking I need to use the other register values/addresses to help me:

```
(gdb) i r
eax            0x64    100
ecx            0xbfffea00    -1073747456
edx            0xbfffef40    -1073746112
ebx            0x405000    4214784
esp            0xbfffef30    0xbfffef30
ebp            0xbfffef58    0xbfffef58
esi            0xbfffefb0    -1073746000
edi            0xb7fb8000    -1208254464
eip            0x401084    0x401084 <phase_3+324>
eflags         0x206    [ PF IF ]
cs             0x73    115
ss             0x7b    123
ds             0x7b    123
es             0x7b    123
fs             0x0    0
gs             0x33    51
```

Any help figuring out what this value is would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Try `x/b $ebp-9`.

Comment: `x/b $ebp-9` gives me `0xbfffef4f: 118`...Hmm. So is `118` the value that's being compared to 100 then? I wonder where that came from :/

Comment: isn't `\230` first byte in octal? I.e. `56`? That's ASCII code for char `'8'`. (EDIT: probably NOT, not sure how \230 should be interpreted). `118` is `'v'`. Well, the `ebp` is often used to point into stack, so use the `x` command to print larger area of future stack at the very beginning, and keep printing it (or use some GUI over gdb) to track the changes...

Comment: You think `v` has any significance? So you suggest I continually run `x/b $ebp` as I step through the debugger? In hopes that `%ebp` started out as one of my inputs?

Comment: `$ebp` is the frame pointer. In any case, there is no guesswork required. The code should quite clearly tell you where the inputs are.

Comment: Not `ebp`, but calculate the fixed address, check `esp` at the beginning, and the code ahead, do some rough estimate how much stack will be used, calculate `esp - that_size`, and keep checking that fixed area while stepping over instructions, especially if you have some recursion or nested subroutines and stack-argument calling is used, it may be quite instructive to watch the memory values. Unfortunately I don't like `gdb`, so I can't help with some handy shortcuts how to achieve that, I prefer debuggers with turbo-debugger-like UI (edb-debugger in linux), where I have "memory view" window.

Comment: Also make sure you first track down how the `ebp` is set up, by 99% if I guess correctly what you are dealing with, then it is used as stack frame pointer, i.e. it will point somewhere into "stack" memory, but in real world the `ebp` is still general purpose register (although on x86 it's always about details, like the usage of `ss` segment in real mode), so the code may eventually use that even in different way, unrelated to stack. As Jester points out, no guesswork. It's deterministic machine. Just keep going per instruction, and check instruction reference manual. Any guess = go back + redo

Comment: *"I assume the -0x9 prefix is referring to another address"* ... and ... seriously, you must study first the subject. Like the AT&T syntax, and x86 instruction list, etc... Assembly is not guessable, as high level language, it doesn't follow "programming language common sense", because it is just "mnemonics" for the HW design of chip, so while the instruction behaviour is very logical from the point of HW CPU designer, it has many irritating inconsistencies and quirks from the point of programmer, and you have zero chance to guess correctly what some instructions do. Study first.

Answer (score 0):

As stated here:

https://www.cs.uaf.edu/2015/fall/cs301/lecture/09_16_stack.html

> al and ah are the 8-bit, "char" size parts of the register.

So, `%al` refers to a `'char'` in the register. Therefore, this `cmp` statement is comparing 2 `char`'s.

Let's refer to the `i r al` command's output:

```
(gdb) i r al
al             0x64     100
```

To determine the `char` value of `al`, we need to take the provided hex value and refer to a [hex-to-ASCII chart](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/ios/12_4/cfg_fund/command/reference/cfnapph.html). The `0x64` hex value for `al` in our case, according to the hex-to-ASCII chart, corresponds to the char `d`. Hey, that's one of our inputs!

So, we know our input of `d` is being compared to `-0x9(%ebp)`.

To find `-0x9(%ebp)`'s value, we need to go to the memory address of `%ebp`, subtract `0x9` from that address' value, and, finally, de-reference *that* address. This is the command to find that value:

```
(gdb) x/b $ebp-9
```

This gives the output of `118` (decimal), which is `0x76` in hex. Refer to the hex-to-ASCII chart once more to find that `0x76` corresponds to the char `v`.

In summary: Our [incorrect] input of `d` was being compared to the [correct] input of `v`.

SOLUTION: Our input of `d` should be changed to `v`.